# Sort the pictures of an album by date on geni.com

Tags: sorting, geni.com

How do I go about sorting the pictures of an alum in Geni.com by date?

Basically you can sort pictures "manually" dragging them around but as I already took my time to put the correct date on every picture I would like them to sort according to those dates.

Comment: Actually I didn't add the "genealogy" tag on purpose because the question is not related to genealogy only to a specific web application (geni.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is you cannot. Geni is still working to improve their album organizing features and several options such as the one I was asking about (and others such as moving images from one page to another page inside an album) are not yet available. I hope they'll be soon because I find these features missing a serious flaw.